# Random element from array in Excel-VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, random

I've stormed the internet and still have not found any solution to this question:

I have an array like so;

```
Dim PayRate As Variant
PayRate = Array(10, 20, 30)

Cells(i, "E").value = PayRate(Int((2 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1))
```

but this will only give me 20 and 30 from the array (elements 1 and 2), I also want element 0 = 10 in the mix ? How do I got about doing that?

Comment: Try: `PayRate(Int((2 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it: `Int(Rnd() * 3) + 1`

`Rnd()` returns a uniformly distributed random number from and including 0 to and not including 1.

**Important**: you must have `Option Base 1` at the top of the module so your PayRate array has lowest bound of 1. Seems like you have this given your question text.

Comment: after all +1 for simplicity

Comment: Agree it's simple but `Int(Rnd() * 3) + 1` never returns `0`. You therefore have to use `Option Base 1` which is typically not the default(?) i.e. most assume the first element of an array is indexed at 0.

Comment: Setting `Option Base 1` and then adding 1 to the result of the random number to convert it to a 1 based index isn't a good idea.  `Option Base 1` changes the sematics of ***the entire code module it's declared in***.  Just use `Int(Rnd() * 3)` with the default indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
Dim PayRate As Variant
PayRate = Array(10, 20, 30)
i = 1
N = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(LBound(PayRate), UBound(PayRate))
Cells(i, "E").Value = PayRate(N)
End Sub
```

I like this because it is independent of the number of elements in the array or whether it is zero-based or one-based.

Comment: This is useless since it may bring duplicated values check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440853/randomise-rows-in-vba)

Comment: @Moreno  There is no requirement to avoid duplicated samples in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim PayRate As Variant

PayRate = Array(10, 20, 30)
indexNumber = Int(Rnd()*3)
Cells(i, "E").value = PayRate(indexNumber)
```